# Terraform ENI Mapping error - does not fall within the subnet's address range

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to map my ENI to my subnet and its throwing an error.

Because there is a for_each loop on the subnet the ENI pointing to it must also have a looped key/value added to it hence the problem

## main.tf

```
# VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = local.json.vpc.cidr

  tags = {
    Name = "vpc"
  }
}

# Subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each = local.api

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = each.value.subnet_cidr
  availability_zone = each.value.subnet_az
}

# ENI
resource "aws_network_interface" "eni" {
  for_each = local.api

  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.public[each.key].id
  private_ips = ["172.16.10.100"] # Might need to add another IP

  tags = {
    Name = "primary_network_interface"
  }
}
```

my locals look like this

```
locals {
  json = jsondecode(file("API.json"))

  api = merge([
    for vpc in local.json : {
      for subnet in vpc.subnets :
      "${vpc.name}-${subnet.name}" => {
        vpc_name    = vpc.name
        vpc_cidr    = vpc.cidr
        subnet_name = subnet.name
        subnet_cidr = subnet.cidr
        subnet_az   = subnet.az
      }
    }
  ]...)
}
```

their output (local.api) from terraform console

```
{
  "vpc-subnet-one" = {
    "subnet_az" = "eu-central-1a"
    "subnet_cidr" = "192.168.1.0/24"
    "subnet_name" = "subnet-one"
    "vpc_cidr" = "192.168.0.0/16"
    "vpc_name" = "vpc"
  }
  "vpc-subnet-two" = {
    "subnet_az" = "eu-central-1b"
    "subnet_cidr" = "192.168.4.0/24"
    "subnet_name" = "subnet-two"
    "vpc_cidr" = "192.168.0.0/16"
    "vpc_name" = "vpc"
  }
}
```

error message

```
   status code: 400, request id: 64e031e5-11ea-4f6d-a03c-9a36a1ff56af

   with aws_network_interface.eni["vpc-subnet-one"],
   on main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_network_interface" "eni":
   20: resource "aws_network_interface" "eni" {



 Error: creating EC2 Network Interface: InvalidParameterValue: Address does not fall within the subnet's address range
       status code: 400, request id: 7842f089-08b4-4042-b928-7830a37ffe28

   with aws_network_interface.eni["vpc-subnet-two"],
   on main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_network_interface" "eni":
   20: resource "aws_network_interface" "eni" {
```

I've followed this [documenation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface) and validated everything else is correct. I still can't seem to figure out what value should be set on `subnet_id`

Bonus cheeky points - I am trying to configure 2 EC2's, Should i give our eni a secondary private_ips?

Comment: What is `local.api`?

Comment: @Marcin It is the JSON output from locals - you have a local.json and local.api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that your IP `172.16.10.100` is invalid for your subnet CIDR range `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.4.0/24`. Obviously this is correct because your IP should be in the correct range. For example:

```
private_ips = ["192.168.1.100"] # for the first subnet
private_ips = ["192.168.4.100"] # for the second subnet
```

Comment: Thank you marcin! I will edit and try again

Comment: Same error persists after change - `Address does not fall within the subnet's address range`

Comment: @Elazar Which address? How did you change your code?

Comment: At first I tried to add it into the json directly and call it from there using `each.key.subnet_ip` (naming was set correctly) and received this `each.value.subnet_ip is "192.168.4.100"

 Inappropriate value for attribute "private_ips": set of string required.`

Then I did it the way you did and realized it was wrong

Comment: @Elazar You have to update your question or make new question with the new version of your code. I don't know what and how did you change your code. Only you know that.

Comment: I just had to add brackets to the each.key and it worked. thanks!